# PdfBox - Unable to extract some text from pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to extract text from a pdf using `pdfbox`. However I am unable to extract all the text from a table. See the image below (snipped from the pdf)

[image]

*(some confidential text has been highlighted)*

I am able to get the text out of the 1st table (in orange) and the 3rd table (General Information one). But I am unable to extract anything out of the 2nd table.

In the output I just see a couple of blank lines between the output of 1st and 3rd table.

Here is my code.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("...."));
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
System.out.println(text);
doc.close();
```

Any inputs or suggestions?

Comment: You should provide a PDF with which this is reproduceable.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#notext "How come I am not getting any text from the PDF document?"

Comment: Can you copy&paste that text from Adobe Reader?

Comment: @mkl yes copy and paste works

Comment: @Setasign Although I am unable to provide the actual pdf, I will try to see if  I can create a new one where this is reproducible.

Comment: @Setasign Interestingly when I export the pdf to a word and recreate another pdf (removing confidential info) and re-run my code on that pdf I am able to extract all the values.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The content was being displayed but it was being re-arranged.

The PDF had a couple of tables placed one after the other. The content of this table was being displayed after content of a few tables placed just after it. So for example if I had 6 tables and this was the 2nd table from the top. It's content was being displayed on 5th position instead of 2nd position.

As suggested by [Tilman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) in comments the use of `pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true)` results into expected content in expected places.

Comment: Use the setSortByPosition() method. Without it, you get the characters in the sequence from the PDF itself, which may or may not be useful.